# Pass f:attribute to f:ajax listener inside composite implementation

Tags: jsf, attributes, jsf-2.2, composite-component

I have the following composite component (relevant code only):

```
    <cc:interface>
        <cc:attribute name="message" type="com.virtuafisica.business.problemsmgmt.entity.Message" required="true" />
        <cc:attribute name="notifiedListener" method-signature="void listener(javax.faces.event.AjaxBehaviorEvent)" />
   </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation> 
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cc.attrs.message.notified}">
            <f:attribute name="msg" value="#{cc.attrs.message}" />
            <c:if test="#{cc.getValueExpression('notifiedListener') != null}">
                <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{cc.attrs.notifiedListener}" />
             </c:if>
        </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>   
    </cc:implementation>
```

This composite is called from a Facelet:

```
<my:message message="#{msg}" notifiedListener="#{problem.changeNotified}"/>
```

And the change event is handled like this in a backing bean:

```
public void changeNotified(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    Message message = (Message) event.getComponent().getAttributes().get("msg");
        if (message == null) {
            logger.log(Level.FINEST, "Null message!");
            return;
        }
        ....
    }
```

The problem is that message is `null` in the backing bean, although the `event.getComponent()` is the right one (is the `HTMLSelectBooleanCheckbox`).

Why isn't the attribute set?

Thank you guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute is set (you can confirm it by determining that `getValueExpression("msg")` didn't return `null`), but the attribute value simply evaluated `null`. Deferred expressions are evaluated at exactly the moment when you want to get the value. So, the `#{cc.attrs.message}` is evaluated at exactly the moment you call `get("msg")` inside the ajax listener method. However, at that point, `#{cc}` doesn't exist anywhere in the EL scope.

The workaround to exactly that technical problem would be to manually put it back in the EL scope (and cleanup afterwards!).

```
UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
UIComponent cc = UIComponent.getCompositeComponentParent(component);
Map<String, Object> requestScope = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();

try {
    requestScope.put("cc", cc);
    Message message = (Message) component.getAttributes().get("msg");
}
finally {
    requestScope.remove("cc");
}
```

Another workaround would be to just obtain it directly from the composite.

```
UIComponent cc = UIComponent.getCompositeComponentParent(event.getComponent());
Message message = (Message) cc.getAttributes().get("msg");
```

Either way, this is only rather clumsy as the backing bean should not need to know that the ajax method is called by a composite. Simply put, you've there a design problem.

Consider creating a backing component and delegating the ajax call from there, so that you can directly pass the `Message` as method argument.

```
@FacesComponent("yourCompositeName")
public class YourComposite extends UINamingContainer {

    public void notifiedListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
        MethodExpression notifiedListener = (MethodExpression) getAttributes().get("notifiedListener");
        Message message = (Message) getAttributes().get("message");
        notifiedListener.invoke(getFacesContext().getELContext(), new Object[] { message });
    }

}
```

Register it as `<cc:interface componentType>`, alter the method attribute to take the `Message` argument and let the `<f:ajax>` call the listener method on the above backing component, which will in turn delegate to the method attribute.

```
<cc:interface componentType="yourCompositeName">
    <cc:attribute name="message" type="com.virtuafisica.business.problemsmgmt.entity.Message" required="true" />
    <cc:attribute name="notifiedListener" method-signature="void listener(com.virtuafisica.business.problemsmgmt.entity.Message)" />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation> 
    <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{cc.attrs.message.notified}">
        <c:if test="#{cc.getValueExpression('notifiedListener') != null}">
            <f:ajax listener="#{cc.notifiedListener}" />
        </c:if>
    </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>   
</cc:implementation>
```

*(note: I removed `event="change"` as that's the wrong one for checkboxes/radiobuttons and the default value is `valueChange` already which is the right one — it evaluates to `event="click"` for checkboxes/radiobuttons)*

Now you can have just this in bean.

```
public void changeNotified(Message message) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you!! But, why 'cc.notifiedListener' and not 'cc.attrs.notifiedListener'?

Comment: Because `#{cc}` references `YourComposite` instance. You want to call the method in there, not the passed-in one.